# What does "critical faculty" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

What does "critical faculty" mean?

> I utter that word of criticism because, in the present circumstances,
> my **critical faculty** is becoming rather blunted from disuse.

or

> They have done a vast amount to stimulate the **critical faculty** among
> consumers.

Comment: Is there a reason why the dictionary didn't help? https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical%20faculties / https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/faculty

Answer (score 3):

The "critical faculty" is the mental ability to make sound judgments. I haven't found a single definition of the collocation, but these are two relevant definitions:

[Merriam-Webster "critical"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/critical)
adjective: exercising or involving careful judgment or judicious evaluation
*critical thinking; a critical commentary on the mayor's proposal*

[Merriam-Webster "faculty"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faculty)
noun 1 : ability, power: such as
a : innate or acquired ability to act or do
*man … how infinite in faculty— William Shakespeare*

The phrase can be used in psychology. Sometimes, it is used in the sense of a habit of mind that must be set aside temporarily to open it to non-habitual ways of perceiving things.

This is a link to the phrase at Google books, to give a sampling of uses:
[Google books "critical faculty"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22critical%20faculty%22&client=firefox-b-1-d&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_jYWdo53rAhVQa80KHSOjAHgQ_AUoAXoECAwQCQ&biw=1201&bih=740)
(As usual, some appearances of the two words together are not that phrase, but other things.)